# AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) with Dart or its frameworks

Tags: dart, amp-html, angular-dart, accelerated-mobile-page, google-amp

Can I create an AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) using dart language or/and AngularDart ? If yes, Is it an easy process like other web language or it's a painful process ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from creating an AMP site w/ Dart. Just follow the docs: https://www.ampproject.org/docs

Keep in mind, Dart web support has been focused on complex app experiences – which is not what AMP is for.

Comment: Many thanks Kevin, glad that the answer came from you .

Comment: Of course. Please mark the question as answered so other folks can keep track.